# link from HTML href to native app

Tags: html, twitter

right now I'm creating a custom tweet button for user to click it and automatically call twitter web intent to share/tweet some link. the method I'm using now is creating an anchor with href to `https://twitter.com/share?url=[some url to share]`

because I will use this on mobile site, is it possible to create similar href or similar link that will instead open the native app to tweet rather than opening a new tab from the browser that will open twitter website? (My goal is to make the native feeling of the tweet button from my mobile site)

any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into iOS URL Schemes for twitter.
The `twitter` scheme, for example, can be invoked with `twitter://user?screen_name=lorenb`.
See [this page](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/twitter) for example, for more info.

This site attempts a more comprehensive list of iOS URL Schemes:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Twitter

Comment: ok, will definitely try this, but how about another devices? Android or WP for example? Haven't tried it yet, but does the `twitter://` URL scheme works on other devices also?

Comment: Yes, it works also on Android, and I guess on any mobile system that has the twitter App installed.

Answer (score 0):

I made Tweetable to do exactly this!

https://github.com/omarish/tweetable

It tests if the app is present on the mobile device, and if so, loads the twitter:// deeplink. Else, it loads the website link if the app is not present (so it plays nice on desktop).