# Alternative for anchor tag in html

Tags: asp.net, html, email

I am currently send a mail in asp.net.

I have done this.

```
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

And also I want to attach one link in this, which will appear in mail as link and it will redirect to mobile screen. So must be not simple text.

```
<a href = \"com.myapp://ScreenId=102&Code=" + auser.VarificationCode + "\" >com.myapp://ScreenId=102&Code=" + auser.VarificationCode + "</a>
```

But it will not appear as link then I put link as.

```
<a href = \"http://com.myapp://ScreenId=102&Code=" + auser.VarificationCode + "\" >com.myapp://ScreenId=102&Code=" + auser.VarificationCode + "</a>
```

It is showing as link but mobile developer can not handle `http://` so any alternative for anchor tag?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1b2p0wfg/) an anchor doesn't need a `http://` or `https://` at the beginning. There are also relative anchor hrefs like `/my/path/` or even `#mySection`. So also your `com.myapp://` should be displayed as link (as you can see in the fiddle). What is the email software you use to display the mail?

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. i tried this but it showing only "com.myapp://ScreenId=102&Code=[CODE]".. it is not showing as Link format. i am not using any software using just gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Rana, I think you do in the correct way. Please check more on these articles below.

[link from HTML href to native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102226/link-from-html-href-to-native-app)

[Android Custom URL to open App like in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065982/android-custom-url-to-open-app-like-in-ios)

I don't know which platform that your mobile app is running. Below is an example of intent on android.

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />

</intent-filter>
```

The following XML snippet shows how you might specify an intent filter in your manifest for deep linking. **The URIs “example://gizmos” and “http://www.example.com/gizmos” both resolve to this activity.**

So as my understanding after reading, both com.myapp... and http://com.myapp... are supported but it depends on your configuration.